# Двойные кавычки в запросе

Tags: sqlite, java

Здравствуйте. Есть запрос вида:

```
Insert into baza Values(str);
```

Если в str содержится символ "(двойная кавычка) - вылетает ошибка синтаксиса. Как лучше обойти такую штуку? Пишу на java.

Comment: Погуглить про Java и БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте параметризированные запросы:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(@"Insert into baza Values(@param)", SQLConnection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param"));
cmd.Parameters["@param"].Value = str;
```

Comment: а почему C#?